# EclipseIDE - append new unit test case into existed test class?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, appender

I have `SampleClass.java` with 5 methods in package `/MyProject/src/sample` and I use Eclipse to generate the unit test class `TestSampleClass.java` in package `/MyProject/src_ut/sample` with 5 test methods and annotations to link backward to my 5 methods in `SampleClass.java`, then I modified those test methods.
Now, I add 3 methods into `SampleClass.java` and I wonder whether or not the IDE can append 3 new test methods for my new 3 methods with link and annotations like the first time I created the `TestSampleClass.java` ?
If it does, please tell me how to do it!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MoreUnit plugin](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) for that.